# Django crispy-forms, BaseGenericInlineFormSet & allow_delete

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, form-layout

I came across a question while working with django-crispy-forms for which I'm unable to get an answer.
I have a rather complex form layout, everything works extremly nice with cripy-forms so far.

One part of the form uses a generic inline formset. This is working as well, but my problem is, that i cannot figure out how to access the delete-checkbox (when having **can_delete=True**)

The corresponding code looks something like:

```
class BaseReleaseReleationFormSet(BaseGenericInlineFormSet): 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.instance = kwargs['instance']
        super(BaseReleaseReleationFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = "id_relation_form"
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.form_tag = False

        base_layout = Row(
                Column(
                       Field('name', css_class='input-small'),
                       #Field('delete', css_class='input-small'),
                       css_class='span3'
                       ),
                Column(
                       Field('url', css_class='input-xlarge'),
                       css_class='span4'
                       ),
                css_class='row relation-row',
        )

        self.helper.add_layout(base_layout)
```

The name and url field are rendered with crispy-forms as desired, but the delete-checkbox appears at the end of the form. And I'm unable to access it in the layout.

Does someone know how to address this problem? Any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the record: you can always do `self.helper.render_unmentioned_fields = True` and then all "hidden" field are also rendered. Then you can check what their names are and explicitly include them in the layout.

Answer (score 11):

Stupid me - figured it out.. The delete field is referenced as "DELETE". (note the capital letters...)

```
    base_layout = Row(
            Column(
                   Field('name', css_class='input-small'),
                   css_class='span3'
                   ),
            Column(
                   Field('url', css_class='input-xlarge'),
                   Field('DELETE', css_class='input-small'),
                   css_class='span4'
                   ),
            css_class='row relation-row',
    )
```