# Django crispy form with formset does not show delete checkbox

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I have some code structure very similar to this example: https://gist.github.com/ibarovic/3092910

Everything is working pretty well, except that the delete checkbox after each Book element is not shown at all. If I change

```
{% crispy formset formset.form.helper %}
```

to

```
{% crispy formset %}
```

the delete checkboxes are shown, but the form does not work anymore (b/c the HTML form tags are used not only once).

I suspect that those checkboxes are not known to the BookForm (b/c they somehow get added later by the inlineformset_factory), so they do not get added to the layout and are ignored. I have no idea how to circumvent that though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to this: [Django crispy-forms, BaseGenericInlineFormSet & allow_delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446744/django-crispy-forms-basegenericinlineformset-allow-delete)

In the BookForm (which gets repeated many times) **init**, you can add something like:

```
self.helper = FormHelper(form=self) # or manual layout
self.helper.form_tag = False

i = self.helper.layout.fields.index('title')
self.helper.layout.insert(i+1, layout.Field("DELETE"))
```

The capital letters "DELETE" field then gets added to each single BookForm...

Comment: Seems to be not necessary anymore in recent crispy-forms version